# When I open exe file,system says cant open flv file

Tags: exe, flv

I have a dvd of toturial movies. The movies are in exe format. When I try to open them, the system says It cant open .flv files. I try to open them with flv player but it doesnt work. What should i do?

Comment: are they exe files or flv files? i doubt theyre exe files if theyre movies, if they are exe files then theyre either names wrong or they are applications

Comment: They are in movie folder so they should be movies. But they have exe format and type is application. Im confused.

Comment: in which case, they appear to be executables, not movies

Comment: So how can i run them?

Comment: you run exe files by double clicking them, or by right clicking and then clicking run/open

Comment: I said before when I try to open them there is an error that says cant open flv file

Comment: Have you tried to install a player which can show Flash Video, e.g., VLC Media Player? Probably the EXE files are just wrappers which decompress a FLV and try to open it with the associated application.

Comment: I tried it. Time is running but there is no sound and picture.